Publish an event to a message channel in Apex
I'm scheduling a deployment from an LWC, and setting a callback using the handleResult() method. When the deployment fails/succeeds, I want to publish an event to a Message Channel that I created which the LWC will subscribe to, to notify the user what happened.
Using an answer on a previous question: How to determine when Queue is complete on LWC
I created the message channel called "DeploymentStatusCallback" and deployed it successfully.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningMessageChannel xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <masterLabel>DeploymentStatusCallback</masterLabel>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <description>Subscribe to this channel to be notified of deployment success/failures in a Lightning Web Component.</description>
    <lightningMessageFields>
        <fieldName>RecordId</fieldName>
        <description>The deployment Id</description>
    </lightningMessageFields>
    <lightningMessageFields>
        <fieldName>Status</fieldName>
        <description>The deployment status</description>
    </lightningMessageFields>
</LightningMessageChannel>

Now, in the handleResult() method, I am trying to instantiate a new instance of that object, set the fields on the Message Channel and then publish it via the EventBus. However, when I try to deploy the APEX I get "Invalid type: DeploymentStatusCallback__e". I also tried with the "__c" suffix as I read that they are actually objects in the guide. Neither works and I still get the same error.
public void handleResult(Metadata.DeployResult result, Metadata.DeployCallbackContext context) {
        if (result.status == Metadata.DeployStatus.Succeeded) {
            DeploymentStatusCallback__e callbackMessage = new DeploymentStatusCallback__e(RecordId__c = result.id, Status__c = result.status);
            EventBus.publish(callbackMessage);
        } else {
            System.debug(' fail : '+ result);
        }
    }

I can't seem to find any guide that is specifically publishing to the messageChannel via Apex, so am I missing the point here and this is just between LWCs? Can you actually do this? Do we just need to use a standard platform event instead and publish to that?

It seems that, as of Winter '25 (API 62.0), it is not possible to publish a message to the Lightning Message Channel from Apex. To me, it sounds logical, as it is an instrument for communication between components across the DOM. For example:

Use Lightning message service to communicate across the DOM within a
Lightning page. Communicate between Visualforce pages embedded in the
same Lightning page, Aura components, and Lightning web components,
including components in a utility bar and pop-out utilities. Choose
whether a component subscribes to messages from the entire
application, or from only the active area.

The Publish on a Message Channel documentation does not mention the possibility of publishing a message from Apex.
It is not a big deal or a problem. Use platform events.
Platform Event
Instead of creating the lightning message channel DeploymentStatusCallback, create a custom platform event DeploymentStatusCallback__c with needed custom fields.
it is possible to publish platform event from Apex:
DeploymentStatusCallback__e callbackMessage = new 
DeploymentStatusCallback__e(RecordId__c = result.id, Status__c = result.status);
EventBus.publish(callbackMessage);

in LWC it is possible to subscribe to platform event using lightning/empApi module. (example copied from documentation)
import {
    subscribe,
    unsubscribe,
    onError,
    setDebugFlag,
    isEmpEnabled,
} from 'lightning/empApi';
...
handleSubscribe() {
    // Callback invoked whenever a new event message is received
    const messageCallback = function (response) {
        console.log('New message received: ', JSON.stringify(response));
        // Response contains the payload of the new message received
    };

    // Invoke subscribe method of empApi. Pass reference to messageCallback
    subscribe(this.channelName, -1, messageCallback).then((response) => {
        // Response contains the subscription information on subscribe call
        console.log(
            'Subscription request sent to: ',
            JSON.stringify(response.channel)
        );
        this.subscription = response;
        this.toggleSubscribeButton(true);
    });
}

handleUnsubscribe() {
    this.toggleSubscribeButton(false);

    // Invoke unsubscribe method of empApi
    unsubscribe(this.subscription, (response) => {
        console.log('unsubscribe() response: ', JSON.stringify(response));
        // Response is true for successful unsubscribe
    });
}

Don't forget to unsubscribe from a platform event on component destruction or once your component doesn't need to be subscribed to it.

Thanks Oleksandr. This is the same conclusion I came to and have implemented it using a platform event in the end.
